# Hittest for two object shapes

Tags: collision-detection, intersection, haxe, hittest, openfl

Suppose we have an object with hitbox having an arbitrary complex shape and an object with circle/polygon as a hitbox. How to detect the collisions of these two objects (not the boundary rectangles, but the actual pixels)? Both objects are opaque Sprites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a snippet of code I found in ActionScript 3 (https://snipplr.com/view/90435/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-as3/) that looks like it should work in OpenFL.

A Haxe version of the code might look like this:

```
public function objectsHit (mc1:DisplayObject, mc2:DisplayObject):Bool {

    var mc1bounds = mc1.getBounds (this);
    var mc2bounds = mc2.getBounds (this);
    var allintersections = (mc2bounds.intersection(mc1bounds));

    for (xval in allintersections.x...(allintersections.x + allintersections.width)) {
        for (yval in allintersections.y...(allintersections.y + allintersections.height)) {
            if (mc2.hitTestPoint (xval, yval, true) && mc1.hitTestPoint (xval, yval, true)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

It might also be possible to use the `hitTestObject` method first, then to use the `hitTestPoint` method second. The general idea is to perform bounding box hit detection first, then to perform point-based collision (which is more expensive) if you need something more exact.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  The texture sprites are from the Flambe engine.  Essentially the bounding box of the collision, then iterate through the collision box checking each pixel.

```
    static public function pixelPerfect(sprite1:SpriteContainer, sprite2:SpriteContainer):Bool
    {
        var collisionRect:Rectangle;

        for (texture1 in sprite1.textures)
        {
            for (texture2 in sprite2.textures)
            {
                collisionRect = CollisionUtil.collisionRect(texture1, texture2);
                if (collisionRect == null) continue;

                if (pixelCollision(texture1, collisionRect) && pixelCollision(texture2, collisionRect))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

static public function pixelCollision(sprite:TextureSprite, collisionRect:Rectangle) 
    {
        var localRectPt:Point = sprite.globalToLocal(collisionRect.x, collisionRect.y);
        localRectPt.x /= Main.GLOBAL_SCALE;
        localRectPt.y /= Main.GLOBAL_SCALE;

        var scaledRect:Rectangle = collisionRect.clone();
        scaledRect.width /= Main.GLOBAL_SCALE;
        scaledRect.height /= Main.GLOBAL_SCALE;

        var PIXEL_DATA_LENGTH:Int = 4;
        var PIXELS_TO_SKIP:Int = 5;
        var resolution:Int = PIXEL_DATA_LENGTH * PIXELS_TO_SKIP;
        var alphaOffset:Int = 3;
        var bytes:Bytes;
        try{
            bytes = sprite.symbol.atlas.readPixels(Math.round(localRectPt.x), Math.round(localRectPt.y), Math.round(scaledRect.width), Math.round(scaledRect.height));
            var n:Int = bytes.length;
            var i:Int = 0;
            while(i+3<n)
            {
                if (bytes.get(i + alphaOffset) > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                i += resolution;
            }
        }
        catch (e:Dynamic)
        {
            Log.trace(e);
        }

        bytes = null;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without Flambe? I suppose I must use Bitmap and its BitmapData, right? Sprites do not seem to have such properties as texture